# Bootstrap col-xs-12 in HTML is not taking full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a simple button link in my page with `container-fluid` and `row` classes so that I can take utilize the whole available width of the page for the link button.

However, my code doesn't result in the button taking full width of the page. Attached is the screenshot of the said output.

Please inform me as to what I'm doing incorrectly. Thanks in advance.

[Basically what I want is that the well in the below screenshot should take 100% (or atleast 90% and centered) of the page width.]

My HTML and CSS codes are mentioned below:

[image: Screen shot]

**My HTML Code:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">   
            <div class="row">
                <section id="access_list_session" class="col-sm-12">
                    <br/>
                    <p id="form-header"> Access Colleague List </p>
                        <br /><br /><br />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4">
                                <i class="fa fa-5x fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="well col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                                <div id="form_link"> 
                                    <a href="xyz.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" style="text-color: blue;"><i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Click to access our Colleague List<br /> <span style="font-size: 10px; text-align:center;"">(Use of this list is subject to our Privacy Policy and other T&C)</span> </a>
                                </div>

                                <br/>
                                <hr>
                                <p> In case of any difficulty please contact the site administrator using the form below.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**My CSS Code**

```
#form_link a
{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.row
{
    padding-top: 60px;
    height: 60em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 solutions IMHO :

Add in .row

```
.row { 
  margin: auto;
}
```

to center your block (see https://jsfiddle.net/os7frkq5/1/)

or simply delete `width: 100% :` 
(see https://jsfiddle.net/os7frkq5/2/ )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you mean but you can try this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

        <section id="access_list_session" class="col-md-12">
            <br/>
            <p id="form-header"> Access Colleague List </p>
            <br /><br /><br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4">
                    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="well col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div id="form_link">
                        <a href="xyz.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" style="text-color: blue;"><i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Click to access our Colleague List<br /> <span style="font-size: 10px; text-align:center;"">(Use of this list is subject to our Privacy Policy and other T&C)</span> </a>
                    </div>

                        <br/>
                        <hr>
                        <p> In case of any difficulty please contact the site administrator using the form below.</p>
                </div>

        </section>

    </div>
```

Comment: `col-xs-12` was supposed to take the whole width of the page. It didn't. As per your suggestion I tried `col-xs-8`, but it further reduces the width of the button instead of increasing.

Comment: Sorry my typo, has to be `col-xs-12` because when hiding the cogs it needs to span the whole page.

Comment: It didn't work. I'm getting the same result with significant space to the right of the `well` (as was seen on my original screenshot)

Comment: @ABor this is strange, the above code is working for me, and when I resize the browser also. Maybe I could be wrong but do you have any additional `css` file along with `boostrap` which could affect the `<section>` tag?

Comment: I've a `.row` class description in my css file. I've added the same as an edit to my original CSS code above.

Comment: Did you try, just for testing, to copy the above code and past it in your page? Maybe you didn't made all the changes. Because on my testing playground it is looking ok.

Answer (score -2):

What you want is the `a` element to use block-display.

```
a { display: block }
```

Read up on the differences between inline and block elements, because it's vital to the way they're laid out.